# Solution of the transport equation is of exponential order

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the transport equation

$\begin{cases}u_{x}(x,y)+u_{y}(x,y)=0,\ x\geq{}y\geq0\\ u(x,0)=f(x),\ x\geq0,\end{cases}$

where $f\in{}C^{1}([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$.

**Q1**. Without solving the equation, how can I show that $f$ being of some exponential order implies the same for $u(\cdot,y)$?
That is, if $|f(x)|\leq{}M\mathrm{e}^{\alpha{}x}$ for $x\geq0$,
where $M,\alpha>0$, then show that $|u(x,y)|\leq{}K_{y}\mathrm{e}^{\alpha{}x}$ for $x\geq{}y$, where $K_{y}>0$ is some constant.

**Q2**. When are we allowed to apply the method of seperation of variables for this equation?

Comment: @Q2: As far as I know you can always try to use method of separation. But in general you might not be able to find a solution to your PDE with the given boundary condition.

Comment: There is no need for any method of solving to see that obviously $u(x,y)=f(x-y)$. Of course, if $f$ is of some exponential order, the same for $u=f(x-y)$. Perhaps this is not what was expected as kind of answer. Perhaps, I don't understand the question.

Comment: @JJacquelin Suppose that we dont know what the solution is. Then, how can we deal with these questions. Think of the times when the equation is written down but we have no explicit solution yet...